# how to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pattern-matching

I'm filtering the text file in nodejs and the "match" regex is giving me error on the filtered array

```
var fs = require("fs");
var finalarray = [];
var data = [];
var data1 = [];

fs.readFile('dataforparsing', function (err, buf) {

  finalarray = buf.toString();// convert the object into the string

  data = finalarray.split("\n");// splitting based on new line

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].match(/sessionid:/g) && !data[i].match(/Input/g)) {// filtering of the rows
      data1[i] = data[i].toString();
      console.log(data1[i] + "\n");
    }
  }

var data3 = [];

for (i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    data3[i] = data1[i].match(/[0-9]{13}/g);
    console.log(data3[i] + "\n");
  }

});
```

The expectation is that the code should work in the last loop as well but it gives error at "data1[i].match(..)" and print the filtered output based on the REGEX expression.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: reason you do not use filter() ??

Comment: "data3[i] = data1[i].match(/[0-9]{13}/g);" gives the TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined.

Comment: i want to filter the values in the data array to data1 array based on the regex match(/[0-9]{13}/g). Hope you understand the problem

Comment: please run this code.. this is minimum reproducible code only the contents in the file is to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you only fill in indexes where you find matches

if (data[i].match .... ) {
   data1[i] = data[i].toString();  <-- that i is killing you
}

so when you do not have a match you have

```
data[0] -- match
data[1] -- undefined
data[2] -- match
```

You want to use push() not set the index

```
data1.push(data[i]);
```

But in the end you are just rewriting filter()

```
var data1 = data.filter(item => item.match(/sessionid:/g) && !item.match(/Input/g))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Arrays's push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to set data1 array elements.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var finalarray = [];
var data = [];
var data1 = [];

fs.readFile('dataforparsing', function (err, buf) {

  finalarray = buf.toString();// convert the object into the string

  data = finalarray.split("\n");// splitting based on new line

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].match(/sessionid:/g) && !data[i].match(/Input/g)) {// filtering of the rows
      data1.push(data[i].toString());

    }
  }

var data3 = [];

for (i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    data3[i] = data1[i].match(/[0-9]{13}/g);
    console.log(data3[i] + "\n");
  }

});
```

Hope this will help.